# AJAX is running correctly but doesn't display fetched data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My PHP query is running fine(based on the response on firebug) but the result its giving me are `[object Object]` on my direct page. So I'm guessing that my problem lies on my javascript because on firebug under the response tab its retrieving all my data on my database

Here is my javascript

```
    function AjaxRetrieve()
            {
              var rid = document.getElementById('trg').value,
            data = {chat: uid, rid: rid, name: user};
 $.ajax({
      url: "includes/getChat.php",
      type: "GET",
      data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
   success: function(result){
     var res = $([]);

        $.each(result[0], function(key, value) {
            res = res.add($('<div />', {text : value}));
        });

        $("#clog").html(res);
   }
});

        }
```

The php script as requested is this

```
        $sql7 = "SELECT   message_content, username , message_time, recipient FROM ".$tbpre."chat_conversation WHERE msgid=:chat";

    $stmt7=$con3->prepare($sql7);
    $stmt7->bindValue( 'chat', $msgd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt7->execute();



  $message_query = $stmt7;


$json = array();

if($message_query->rowCount() > 0) {
    while($message_array = $stmt7->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $json[] = $message_array;
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

I'm not that familiar yet on JQUERY/AJAX/Javascript so I'm not actually sure if what I'm doing is correct I just based some of my codes on jquery's documentation and some 
 suggestions from our fellow members here

Comment: could you post the json data received on successfull ajax call

Comment: please show your json data

Comment: Show your php code and json returned...

Comment: Master @dreamweiver
Here are the response I have cut them short cause its so many
`[[{"message_content":"asdafgga","username":"ab","message_time":"2014-04-03 14:50:03","recipient":"cd"},{"message_content":"hey","username":"ab","message_time":"2014-04-03 14:50:17","recipient":"cd"}]]`

Comment: Master @Madhu I have edited and included my php script as you have requested

Answer (score 1):

Change your success callback like below, you have an array of objects.

```
   success: function(result){
        var container = $("#clog");

        $.each(result, function(i, message) {
            $.each(message, function(key, value) {
                container.append($('<div />').html(key + ':' + value));
            });
        });
   }
```

***Edit:***

And you have to change `fetchAll` to `fetch` in you while loop.

```
while($message_array = $stmt7->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $json[] = $message_array;
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

Or just use `fetchAll` without while loop:

```
$json = $stmt7->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Hi I used your code and the result was `0:[object Object]
1:[object Object]
2:[object Object]`

Comment: @user256009 See my edit. There is wrong place in your php code too.

Comment: this worked but is there a way for me to display my json result individually? because I need to style the username result and message result from JSON

Answer (score 1):

The way your constructing the json data is wrong,try this way

```
$json =array();
$i=0;
if($message_query->rowCount() > 0) {
  while($message_array = $stmt7->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $json[$i]= $message_array;
     $i++;
  }

echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hi this code doesn't seem to work to me I get a message that ` Array to string conversion`

Comment: @user256009: didnt notice that, try now with edited code

Comment: `[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]`
this is the output =(